# Java 8 use of optional

Tags: java, spring

I have two methods I'd like to improve using optional and any other tool,

```
 @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("No user found with username '%s'.", username));
        } else {
            return user;
        }
    }

    public void changePassword(String oldPassword, String newPassword) {

        Authentication currentUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String username = currentUser.getName();

        if (authenticationManager != null) {
            LOGGER.debug("Re-authenticating user '"+ username + "' for password change request.");

            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, oldPassword));
        } else {
            LOGGER.debug("No authentication manager set. Can't change Password!");

            return;
        }

        LOGGER.debug("Changing password for user '"+ username + "'");

        User user = (User) loadUserByUsername(username);
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(newPassword));
        userRepository.save(user);

    }
```

First solution was to do 
`Optional.ofNullable(user).orElseThrow()` but I couldn't use the string format here for the `UsernameNotFoundException`. I don't want to lose the message I have written in the exceptions.

Any suggestions on how to improve this code?

Comment: Do not use optionals that way. They're not a replacement for if statements. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327957/should-java-8-getters-return-optional-type/26328555#26328555

Answer (score 6):

Optionals do not improve your code. You're using if statements and null checks just like they are intended to be used. There is no need to improve anything there.

Edit: If-statements and null-checks are not evil. There is no need to try to get rid of either one and Optionals were not intended to replace them. The evil is having an API made by someone else and not knowing if it returns a null or not. Optionals were intended to give the person reading the code and the compiler compiling it a strongly typed fact about the possibility of a *method return value* not existing.

If I have to try to find something worth mentioning from your code it's the use of heavy String.format to create a trivial exception message. Just use concatenation like in the logging statements. :)

Comment: Well, in fact my sonar always tells me not to use concatenation in logging statements, but ("... {}", x) instead ;-)

Comment: We don't know if it's Log4j or not.

Comment: "`Optional` does not improve your code."  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

For first method:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(userRepository.findByUsername(username))
               .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("No user found with username '%s'.", username)));
```

The second method does not need an Optional.
Fail fast by changing the method to start by checking if the authenticationManager is null, log and exit (guard clause).
Never the less, having fields which could be null is not a good sign, there's more to clean there. Maybe Null Object Pattern could help, or something else. Nullable class fields are bad, Optional class fields are not an option, polymorphous or Null Object Pattern could be the answer.

Update:
For first method, a cleaner way is to have userRepository.findByUsername return an optional. Methods with "find" in their name are a natural candidate for Optional return. This would remove the need for Optional.ofNullable.

```
return userRepository.findByUsername(username)
               .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("No user found with username '%s'.", username));
```

Comment: Please, no. You're abusing optionals. They were not meant to replace if-statements. There is a post by the architect who designed them on Stack Overflow. TLDR: They're meant for public method return values only.

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327957/should-java-8-getters-return-optional-type/26328555#26328555

Comment: 1. Fantastic comment. 2. That link says *"Our intention was to provide a limited mechanism for library method return types where there needed to be a clear way to represent "no result"..."*  This kinda squares with my own personal take on `Optional`.  That it's intended for *libraries* (and streams in particular) and not necessarily a general purpose type for folks to sprinkle their code with.  Usually in user code it just makes the code untidy and complicated for no gain.  C.f. [Poltergeists anti-pattern.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poltergeist_(computer_programming))

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to not use Optional for simple NULL check, because it's creating necessary object. If you use them, it looks elegant style but impact in performance.